# Fastest transfer of data from MSSQL to MySQL via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I need to store data from a remote MS SQL db into a local MySQL db; I need to do this using PHP.

The fetching of the data from MSSQL is simple enough:

```
SELECT orderRef
     , orderValue
  FROM remoteTbl
```

This results in 100k rows.  I want to store this in a local MySQL database using PHP.  Simply enough, I can do (with the addition of another field I want) :

```
while(list($orderRef, $orderValue) = mssql_fetch_array($result)){

mysql_query("INSERT INTO localTbl (orderRef, orderValue, updated)
                           VALUES ('$orderRef', '$orderValue', NOW())");

} // done all rows
```

This seems wasteful for 100k rows of data though.

Is there some way I can do this more efficiently?

- Updated further to comments:
- by using the PHP resource from the MSSQL query perhaps?
  I need to do things with the data, and the MSSQL DBMS is read only.

Thanks

Comment: [Create a linked server between the instances?](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,123221,123221)

Comment: Why do you need to transfer these to your database?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I appreciate the suggestion and the URL but for assorted reasons, I need to do this via PHP.

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey Because I need to do things with the data and the MSSQL DBMS is read only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use mysqli since mysql functions aren't going to be around any more but to speed this up you could do one big insert statement like so.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO localTbl (orderRef, orderValue, updated) VALUES ";

while(list($orderRef, $orderValue) = mssql_fetch_array($result)){

    $sql_rows[] = "('$orderRef', '$orderValue', NOW())";

}

mysql_query($sql . implode(',', $sql_rows) . ';');
```

Comment: That's excellent, thanks!  I hadn't thought of building a single query from the result - and that's a really elegant way of doing it too, with the array and implode.  And yes, I know I should be using mysqli... perhaps this will be the first area of this particular project to move onto it!

Comment: With a 100K rows I would imagine you run out of memory doing it like this.

Comment: @troelskn Interesting.  There might be more than 100k rows and also, it's likely that I'll need to pull more columns sometimes.  Is there another approach or am I limited to simply interating over rows as required?  That's not a problem since it's a local DBMS on a LAMP server, it'll fly through.  It just seems inelegant.

Comment: you could add a `counter` in your while loop ... and `if($counter == 100){ mysql_query($sql . implode(',', $sql_rows) . ';'); unset($sql_rows); $counter = 0; } $counter++;`